# How can I hide windows from another workspace from showing in the taskbar?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock, taskbar

How do I prevent windows from another workspace showing an icon in the taskbar (Ubuntu Dock)?

Example:

- Firefox running on workspace 1
- Files running on workspace 2
- When I am in workspace 1 I would like to have only Firefox shown in
  the taskbar.
- When I switch to workspace 2 I would no longer see Firefox in the
  taskbar but instead I would see Files

This is configurable in other desktop systems such as LDXE but I cannot find the options in a standard Ubuntu 20.04 installation (running GNOME).